# Flow - Object may be null, but it is clearly defined in the constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I have something like the following:

```
// @flow

type MyObject = {
  a: number,
  b: number
};

class MyComponent extends Component {
  myObject: ?MyObject = null; // null on init
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.myObject = {
      a: 1,
      b: 2
    };
  }

  render() {
    return <h1>{this.myObject.a}</h1>;
  }
}
```

This returns me a flow error on `this.myObject.a`, stating:

```
Cannot get this.myObject.a because property "a" is missing in null or undefined [1].
```

Obviously I can do a check to see if `this.myObject` is an object, but is there a way in the current version of flow (0.72.0), so that I don't have to do these largely redundant checks?

I know I may be asking for too much, but I just wanted to hear your thoughts on how this should best be done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use

```
myObject: MyObject;
```

not

```
myObject: ?MyObject = null;
```

If we desugar the class field initializer, your code basically ends up looking like this:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.myObject = null;
    this.myObject = {
      a: 1,
      b: 2
    };
  }
  //...
  }
}
```

...because instance fields are initialized right at the beginning of the constructor (immediately after the call to `super`, in subclasses; at the very beginning in top-level classes). (Details in [the proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields), specifically the proposed spec text [here](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-class-fields/#the-super-keyword) [for subclasses] and [here](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-class-fields/#[[construct]]) [for base classes].)

So no need for the initial `null` or the `?` on the type. Removing them removes the problem.

Comment: Well, that completely went over my head. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Somehow I completely forgot that the statements outside the constructor get compiled down into the constructor, whereas your code example immediately cleared my head up. :)

Comment: @think123 - Ah! Sorry, I misunderstood your comment. I thought you meant the *answer* went completely over your head. I get it now. :-) (And yes, lots of people make that same mistake of thinking there's some interval in there, it's not just you.)